# Do closure properties for languages go the other way?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines

For example I know the union of 2 either decidable or recognizable languages is decidable or recognizable. But say the union of two languages is decidable, does this tell us anything about themselves?

Comment: Very little, other than the fact that the union is decidable. The union of a language with its complement is decidable, for example.

Comment: @rici Make an answer?

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't tell us much. Intuitively, union erases information; it's not normally a reversible operation.

So, for example, the union of a language with its complement is clearly decidable and recognizable, regardless of any category in which the language might or might not belong.